# Is there a way use SAML IDP with Sonatype nexus repository manager?

Tags: azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, saml, nexus, nexus3

We want to migrate our old nexus to new one. bur in the new one I wanna use SAML Idp for authentication but not found anything about it. Is there a way to configure SAML Idp in nexus? And our nexus is not Pro version of course.

Comment: SAML integration is available, but it requires a license:  https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3/SAML

Comment: Thank you for comment. Yes I saw that I need to do it without license @rseddon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [patch for Nexus OSS with authorization via SSO and tokens](https://github.com/a-langer/nexus-sso). It implements authentication via Single Sign-On (SSO) using a SAML identity provider such as Keycloak, Okta, ADFS and others.

Solution distributed as [docker container](https://github.com/a-langer/nexus-sso/pkgs/container/nexus-sso) and [compose.yml](https://github.com/a-langer/nexus-sso/blob/main/compose.yml) configuration which may be extended with "compose.override.yml" (for example, pass additional files to the container):

```bash
git clone https://github.com/a-langer/nexus-sso.git
cd ./nexus-sso
cp ./_compose.override.yml ./compose.override.yml
# Change compose.override.yml for you settings and run service
docker compose up -d
```

Authentication may be configured with environment variables in [.env](https://github.com/a-langer/nexus-sso/blob/main/.env) file, for more flexible settings, can make changes directly to [shiro.ini](https://github.com/a-langer/nexus-sso/blob/main/nexus-pac4j-plugin/src/main/config/shiro.ini). However, this also requires that the configuration files of service provider (ex., [sp-metadata.xml](https://github.com/a-langer/nexus-sso/blob/main/nexus-pac4j-plugin/src/main/config/sp-metadata.xml)) and identity provider (ex., [metadata-okta.xml](https://github.com/a-langer/nexus-sso/blob/main/nexus-pac4j-plugin/src/main/config/metadata.xml) or [metadata-keycloak.xml](https://github.com/a-langer/nexus-sso/blob/main/nexus-pac4j-plugin/src/main/config/metadata-keycloak.xml)) will be passed to the container. Examples of creating SAML configurations see in "[Keycloak SAML integration with Nexus application](https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/1500000976522-Keycloak-SAML-integration-with-Nexus-Applications)".